# How can I change the look of Totems buttons,(Play,pause,etc)

Tags: themes, totem

I was wondering if it is possible to change the look of totems play pause buttons I really dislike the look of them they don't really match up...Is there a config file I must edit to make them look as they did in 10.10?

Comment: I have no experience of 10.10. Could you describe a bit more what exactly are the aspects you dislike? IMO, the foreground **color** of the "icons" can be changed by editing stuff in gtk3 and without changing icon themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are part of the icon theme, so if you switch icon themes, they should switch along with the theme.